# solution of recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = \frac {1}{x_n + 1}$

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

$$x_{n+1} = \frac {1}{x_n + 1}; x_1 > 0$$

How to transform it into the form $x_n = $? I need the solution in order to check if it converges at any $x_1 > 0$.

Comment: You do know that you don't necessarily need the solution in order to check for convergence, right?

Comment: No matter what you put in there for $x_n$, it's pretty obvious that $x_{n+1}$ is less than $1$. At least once it's been pointed out. As for convergence, a limit $x$ needs to statisfy
$$
x = \frac{1}{x + 1}
$$
since it can't be a limit unless it's a stationary point. Now just solve that equation and check that for any $x_n$, $x_{n+1}$ is closer to this $x$.

Comment: And that means $x_{n+2}$ is larger than ...

Comment: Check the [convergence of monotone sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal This sequence isn't monotone. If you consider every other term, however, then it is.

Comment: This sequence can be represented as a continued fraction as $n\to\infty$ by $[0;1,1,1,1,1,…]$ which is essentially $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: @Panda, no. Then what should I do?

Comment: @Arthur, the roots are $-0.5 \pm \frac {\sqrt 5} {2}$. How to know which on is limit?

Comment: @John Try a few (very) different values for $x_0$, calculate up to $x_4$ or something, see if you see any patterns. It's how any mathematician would do it if he didn't see a solution right away.

Comment: @John Can any term of the sequence ever be negative? Positive? How does that help you choose?

Comment: @Arthur, if the 1st term is positive, then all subsequent are positive. As a result. there is no need to check :)

Comment: @John Mind you, you've just figured out what the limit has to be _if_ it exists. But knowing your limits is half the battle.

Comment: Also, if you are just interested in the closed form solution check here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Bn%2B1%5D%3D1%2F%281%2Bx%5Bn%5D%29

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

One nice way to do linear fractional recurrences is to use matrices.  If $a/b=x$, then $c/d = 1/(x+1)$, where
$$
\left(\begin{aligned}0\qquad 1 \cr 1\qquad 1\end{aligned} \right)
\left(\begin{aligned}a\cr b\end{aligned}\right) = 
\left(\begin{aligned}c\cr d\end{aligned}\right)
$$
So we can get a formula for $x_n$ if we know a formula for the $n$th power of that $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. First of all you can prove by induction that all of the $x_n$'s are strictly positive.
2. Using that, prove that they are also lesser than 1.
3. From the above two steps, the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ lies in the compact interval $[0,1]$,so it has a convergent subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}$
4. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists and is equal to $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try

$$a(n)\to \frac{\mathcal C \;\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n+\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n}{\mathcal C \; \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^{n+1}
   +\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: These look like Fibonacci numbers to me!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Then

\begin{align}
&a=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+...}}}\\&a=\frac{1}{1+a}\\&a(a+1)=1\\&a^2+a-1=0\\&a=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align}

Since there is no negative term or subtraction in the sequence, we omit the negative solution.

$\displaystyle \therefore a=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding the limit, assume $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$, then

$$ a=\frac{1}{a+1} \implies a^2+a-1=0 \implies a=\frac{-1 \bar{+} \sqrt{5}} {2}. $$

Now, you should pick up the right limit.